# How request CONNECT with Apache HttpComponents Client

Tags: java, http, httprequest, apache-httpcomponents

Apache says:

> "HttpComponents Client is a successor of and replacement for Commons
>   HttpClient 3.x. Users of Commons HttpClient are strongly encouraged to
>   upgrade."

In package *org.apache.http.client.methods* almost all Http methods are supported:

- OPTIONS (HttpOptions)
- GET (HttpGet)
- HEAD (HttpHead)
- PATCH (HttpPatch)
- POST (HttpPost)
- PUT (HttpPut)
- DELETE (HttpDelete)
- TRACE (HttpTrace)

But what is with the method CONNECT? How to execute a CONNECT request?

("Before" in *org.apache.commons.httpclient* there exist the ConnectMethod for method CONNECT.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can easily create a CONNECT request but I am not entirely sure what you intent to do with it

```
HttpRequest connect = new BasicHttpRequest("CONNECT", "somehost:80");
```

HttpClient creates CONNECT requests internally when establishing an SSL tunnel through a proxy server.

Comment: I'd like to use it for a test tool to be able to test the behaviour of all http methods for some uri.